# Android: How to fit splash screen background image to full screen

Tags: android, react-native, splash-screen

I have splash screen, which contain only a background image. I'm trying that

*Image stretch to full screen width if image width is lesser than actual device screen width.*

**AND**

*Image shrink to full screen width if image width is more than actual device screen width.*

**AND**

*Image stretch to full screen height if image height is less than actual device screen width.*

**AND**

*Image shrink to full screen height if image height is more than actual device screen width.*

Here is my current code of drawable/splash_screen.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/backgroundImage"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

And this file is getting consumed in style.xml

````
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    </style>
    <style name="SplashTheme" parent="AppTheme">
      <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
    </style>
</resources>```

Is there any way to achieve this?
````

Comment: Can you show an example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: add the activity_layout.xml where you have consumed this.

Comment: @xbadal, consuming in style.xl